# Linq add same items in the same list

Tags: c#, linq

So I have a class of products:

```
class Product{
    public int id;
    public int price;
    public string product_name;
}

var BoughtProductList = new List<Product>();
BoughtProductList .Add(new Product() { id = 1, price = 3 product_name = "orange" });
BoughtProductList .Add(new Product() { id = 2, price = 2 product_name = "apple" });
BoughtProductList .Add(new Product() { id = 2, price = 2 product_name = "apple" });
BoughtProductList .Add(new Product() { id = 3, price = 3 product_name = "banana" });
```

Now I want to put it in a table so it will show me all the bought products, but i dont want to see the apple product twice.
How can i go over that list in linq and without creating a new instance of that class and add the same product id's to see the sum of money i got selling that apple in that list.

Comment: It is not really clear what you want to achieve. Please give a sample of the expected output.

Comment: Also why do you need a solution "without creating a new instance of that class"?

Comment: @nemesv makes sense to use a different class (whether defined or anonymous) so that there isn't an object in the system representing an apple with a price of 4, when it means an apple with a total price of 4.

Comment: `boughtProductList.GroupBy(p => new { id = p.id, product_name = p.product_name }, (p, g) => new { id = g.id, product_name = g.product_name , totalPrice = p.price.Sum() })` or somthing like that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from produce in BoughtProductList
group produce.price by new {produce.id, produce.product_name} into grp
select new{grp.id, grp.product_name, TotalPrice = grp.Sum()};
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is perform a `GroupBy` on the product's `id` property.  Once you do that you can add the `id` and `product_name` from each group and know that it will be distinct.  You can also `Sum` over the price of each group (or just multiply the count by the price) to get the sum of money earned selling that product.

Answer (score 1):

```
var newBoughtProductList = new List<Product>();//create new list

for (int i = 0; i < BoughtProductList.Count; i++)//search old list
{
    Product currentProduct = BoughtListProduct[i];//get current product

    if (!newBoughtProductList.Contains(currentProduct)) //see if duplicate
        newBoughtProductList.Add(currentProduct);       //add product

    else 
    {
        int copyingProduct = BoughtProductList.FindIndex(currentProduct);
        //get duplicates index

        newBoughtProductList[copyingProduct].price += 
           newBoughtProductList[copyingProduct].price;//add to price of duplicate
    }
}
```

This basically searches the list and adds none duplicates, then if something is a duplicate, it increases the price by the duplicate's price. *Note: This does not use `linq` (but you probably knew that)* Hope this helps!

Comment: Question asks for LINQ but you use no LINQ in your answer.

Comment: Oh I must have forgotten that part

Comment: Searching a `List` is also not particularly efficient.  You should use a hash based structure to store the distinct values so it will scale much better.